# jQuery: Use the same function for multiple ids

Tags: jquery

i'm using this

```
jQuery('#mydiv').datetimepicker({ ... });
```

How can i use this function for more than just one ID?

Thought something like this should do the job but it doesn't :(

```
jQuery('#mydiv','#anotherdiv).datetimepicker({ ... });
jQuery('#mydiv|#anotherdiv).datetimepicker({ ... });
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: give your divs a common class, then `$('.myclass').datetimepicker...`

Comment: JQuery ('#result, #mydiv') jQuery nesnesi bölme sözdizimi ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single argument with the IDs separated with commas, not separate arguments.

```
jQuery('#mydiv,#anotherdiv').datetimepicker({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the respective Divs a class name, then reference them like this:

```
jQuery('.className').datetimepicker({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

A common class would be the best solution, as @simon suggested.

If you absolutely need to use IDs (eg you can only modify the JS, and not the DOM), you can loop through an array of IDs:

```
$.each(['mydiv', 'anotherdiv'], function (index, value)
{
    $.('#' + value).datepicker({ ... });
}
```